# Error running coffee code with pm2: Error: spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/.bin/coffee ENOENT

Tags: coffeescript, pm2

After I upgraded pm2 from `2.1.5` to `3.4.1` I started to get the following error when I try to start/restart an app `pm2 restart api`:

```
PM2      | App [api:6] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [api:6] online
PM2      | Error: spawn /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/.bin/coffee ENOENT
PM2      |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:247:19)
PM2      |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:431:16)
PM2      |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
PM2      | App [coffee:10] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
```

I tried to install coffee for pm2 with `pm2 install coffee` but it didn't help - I see a lot of this in the `pm2 logs`:

```
PM2      | App [coffee:11] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [coffee:11] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [coffee:11] online
PM2      | App [coffee:11] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [coffee:11] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [coffee:11] online
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install coffeescript version 1 for pm2 run

```
pm2 install coffee-script
```

To install coffeescript version 2 run

```
pm2 install coffeescript
```